# Xcode update required for developing on new iOS versions

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, ios11, apple-developer

Why is it important to download the new version of Xcode when there is a new iOS version released?

Suppose I installed iOS 11 on my mobile and I try to start developing an app with Xcode 8.3 (which does not support this new version of iOS), it will not work.

Sometimes, I also have to download new version of macOS.

Comment: @KKRocks  what will happen if i set 9.0 target ?

Comment: question is why always need to download large file of xcode  when any release of new iOS version (I know new xcode support new SDK of OS). and also problem with new xcode doesnt support the MacOS too.Take an Example iOS11 device only support new XCOde 9 ,and new Xcode onsupport  MacOS 10.12.4 and above

Comment: The large downloads are only needed because this is the beta program. And the very short answer is because this makes it easier for Apple if they don't need to support everything.

Answer (score 0):

For running development code on a device, Xcode has knowledge about the different versions of iOS that it can work with.

If you were trying to build and run on an iOS device with a new version of iOS, Xcode is set up to say it does not know about that version and will not work.

This allows Apple to update the way Xcode talks with iOS devices during development without newer iOS versions needing to remain backwards compatible.